# In python how can I unstack values counting 0 to the end until new id# is found?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, counter

```
a = []
    for i in range(10):
        a.append((str(i) + 'b'))
        a.append((str(i +2) + 'b'))
        a.append((str(i +3) + 'b'))
        a.append((str(i +4) + 'b'))

    df = pd.DataFrame(a)
    df.value_counts()
```

output:
[4b     4
 5b     4
 9b     4
 8b     4
 6b     4
 7b     4
 3b     3
 11b    3
 10b    3
 2b     2
 12b    2
 13b    1
 0b     1
 1b     1

to>>>>
4b 1
4b 2
4b 3
4b 4
5b 1
5b 2
5b 3
5b 4
3b 1
3b 2
3b 3
etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, by using `cumcount`

```
df['cnt']=df.groupby(0).cumcount()+1
df.sort_values([0,'cnt'],inplace=True)
```